# How to find count of cells containing one or more specific words

Tags: google-sheets, countif, formulas

I have a column with various text inputs. I'd like to count the number of cells that include either "word1" or "word2". So that if a single cell contains one or more of these it counts as one.

I've managed to make a formula that I think counts *all* occurrences of "word1" and "word2", but I'm only after the amount of cells containing one of them (or any number of them).

What is the formula for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an array formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMPRODUCT(((ISNUMBER(SEARCH("word1",A1:A5))+ISNUMBER(SEARCH("word2",A1:A5)))>0)*1))
```

That formula was based on [barry houdini's answer](https://superuser.com/a/590254/219090) a while ago.

Just change the range as required.

Comment: @pnuts Oh, no worries, it can happen to everyone :)

Comment: Thank you. This seems to do exactly what I need :)